# Virtualbox memory usage, Xubuntu Host, Windows 7 x64 guest. Virtualbox 4.3.6

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, memory, virtual-machine

In htop (on the host) under the RES column, the memory usage of the Windows 7 guest is sometimes 500-600MB or even more than the allocated memory. With a Linux guest, it's usually not more than 100MB higher. Does anyone know exactly why this happens and what sort of activities in the Windows guest would likely cause it? It doesn't happen every time.

I have 4GB RAM, I run the Windows guest for development and a Linux guest for browsing... so it ends up cutting things pretty close. If I knew what activities in the guest are more likely to cause it, I'd avoid those when possible.

[Edit: I overlooked background network usage in the guest. Heavy network usage in the guest makes this happen. It's worth noting I'm not using default TCP settings if that makes any difference, I changed them because of slow upload speed in the guest. This is less than ideal but I can live with it, I just overlooked it before I asked this question. ]

Answer (score 0):

At [1](http://mugurel.sumanariu.ro/linux/the-difference-among-virt-res-and-shr-in-top-output/) RES is quiet good decribed. Based on that I've say your Windows really is using that memory and therefor VBox is also allocating them.